# Integration of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax-be^x}}{c^2+x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, gamma-function

Marginalizing out one of the variable of my Bayesian model I arrived at an integral $I(a,b,c)$ given by:

$$I(a,b,c) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax-be^x}}{c^2+x^2} dx, \;\;a \in \Bbb{N}, \;\; (b, c) \in \Bbb{R^+}.$$

I wonder if there is a way to get an analytic solution but it seems that contour integration fail for this integral. Ultimately I'm interesting in the ratio $\frac{I(a,b,c_1)}{I(a,b,c_2)}$ but it doesn't seems to make the problem easier.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Just for fun: $$I(a,b,c)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ct}}{2c}\left(\frac{\Gamma(a+it)}{b^{a+it}}+\frac{\Gamma(a-it)}{b^{a-it}}\right)dt.$$

Comment: @metamorphy thank you for your thought on this problem, could you give me the step to arrived at that formula ?

Comment: @Geoff: Easy, use $\frac1{c^2+x^2}=\color{gray}{\frac1c\int_0^\infty e^{-ct}\cos xt\,dt}=\frac1{2c}\int_0^\infty(e^{-(c+ix)t}+e^{-(c-ix)t})\,dt$, exchange the integrations, substitute $e^x=y$, and finally use $\Gamma(s)/b^s=\int_0^\infty y^{s-1}e^{-by}\,dy$.